# Can one tear a plastic ring off of a bottle on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Is one allowed to tear off a plastic ring on bottles ex: those bottles of a gallon of water that you have to tear off the plastic ring around it to use it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, part of the problem breaking seals on שבת is by doing so, you destroy print. Many soda/juice/water, etc. bottles have print around the seal noting manufacturer code, date of expiration, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw a teshuvah from Shemiras Shabbos K'hilchasah in the name of R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach that it is mutar (permitted).

Part of the reasoning is that the cap and bottle are already fully functioning vessels (therefor no melocho of Makeh b'Patish or Boneh). The disposable strip/tab is attached there (usually by law) to show if someone tampered with the contents. (not as part of the cap's purpose or intention to permanently seal). He says there is also no melocho of tearing (even if it appears like a segregated line). (kor-eah)

The truth is, that the entire cap and tab as one unit can usually be pried off (easily by hand)and reused as a lid anyway.

Some poskim say it is better to open it before Shabbos. Some poskim say it is better to pry it off (even with plyers (allowed because of using keli Shemelachto L'issur for a permitted purpose) if done on Shabbos (see R' Dovid Ribiat 39 Melachos). Many people follow the lenient opinion to simply open it on Shabbos in the usual manner without worrying about it before Shabbos.